SPARKLINE in google sheets (german local) not producing the correct output
I am trying to create a budget using the default google sheets template. SPARKLINE creates bars but they do not work.
Here are the functions.
=SPARKLINE(C21;{"charttype"\"bar";"max"\max(C21:C22);"color1"\"#AEB7C0"})

=SPARKLINE(C22;{"charttype"\"bar";"max"\max(C21:C22);"color1"\"#334960"})

Cell C21 is 1.861,43 € 
Cell C22 is 1.062,04 €
I have tried to strip the € and replace the , with a . but it still doesn't work

Share a test sheet showcasing your scenario since the logic most likely depends on the data(+format type) you have in cells C21, C22

Is this format #,##0.00 "€" used in cells?
It feels like you've stumbled upon a bug. The point is that in a sparkline, the maximum value found using the max(range) formula must be an integer. Anyway, if you change 1.861.43 € to 1.861.00 € or 1.861 €, then the sparkline works fine.

@BorisBaublys is correct. I added a ROUND function to the cells SPARKLINE relies on and that fixed the problem

You can try this:
=SPARKLINE(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(C21, "€", "")); {"charttype", "bar"; "max", MAX(VALUE(C21:C22)); "color1", "#AEB7C0"})
=SPARKLINE(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(C22, "€", "")); {"charttype", "bar"; "max", MAX(VALUE(C21:C22)); "color1", "#334960"})

The substitute should get rid of € without you having to clear it. I also introduced 'VALUE' for the maximum and minimum.

Hi,
Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The bars are still the same size.
